# jquery validate not work send mail

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, contacts

I have small problem. I created a form with jquery validated.
validation works to perfection, I just do not get the mail ago.
I'll explain:
if I take off my jquery validation to the form I receive the mail correctly, if I insert it again to validate the email did not arrive more...
costs am I doing wrong?

This is the html code and jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/Je7ep/

this is the code php to send mail that works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/daArB/

Comment: Which jquery you are using for validation?

Comment: Can I give you pattern which work solid in HTML5 tags?

Comment: Thanks for your comment ...
I'm using jQuery validation plug-in 1.6

Comment: ok can i see the documentation or link from which you use it in your form

Comment: yes this is the section contact...
http://byenne.com/contact.html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hvph9/ check this out..this is working by adding that script above

Comment: jquery validate the script works correctly, even before it worked ...
the only problem is I do not get the mails: (

Comment: means you getting error in mail.php as you are getting the values of names=email?

Comment: there is no error in the php file, because if I take off my plugins validated the mail I receive.
if I put the plugin does not validate the email I get more.
so I think it is a mistake due to the plugin.

Comment: I can't understand the problem...mean if you validate the mail you didn't get the value but as you remove it then you get the value of mail right?

Comment: the problem is as follows:

Case 1: If I use the jquery form validation, the mail not arrive.
Case 2: If I take my form validation in jquery, the mail arrives correctly.

:(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887041/jquery-form-validation-and-submit-scripts-conflict check this one similar problem

Comment: I given you link check that out it given the method but in placed of GET u have to POST

Comment: Ah ok perfect thanks! i read now!

Comment: if any problem contact me again.Here is code

Comment: $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mail.php',
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            complete: function(results) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#loading").css("display", "none");
                    $("#response").css("display", "block");
                }, 1500);
            }

Comment: yessssss! I already did! everything works! thanks a lot! are in debt!

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a line to the send mail to log whether or not the code ran fully?

It could be simply an error in your mail server setup as the code appears to work fine.

Try and implement the Logger mentioned here :

http://www.redips.net/php/write-to-log-file/

and then have it log at the end of the send mail that it has completed.